# What is the proper way to write a letter in place of its full name? /a/, “b,” (c,) or ⟨d,⟩ or another?

Tags: punctuation, names

I was in a conversation with a friend and he kept putting letters in forward-slashes -- I know and use the I.P.A. so to me that is confusing, but I have always seen letters put in English-Style Quotation Marks (“”) in English. Is there a proper way? If I recall, in when using the international phonetic alphabet, you separate the letters with the angled-brackets (⟨⟩) from the sounds they make which are put in forward slashes (//.) That is fine, however, this is general English, not a pronunciation lesson.

For example:
"Yesterday, Gary accidentally called a /G/ a /J/."

I would, and always have, written this:
"Yesterday, Gary accidentally called a 'G' a 'j.'"

Writing just the letter as opposed to:

"Yesterday, Gary accidentally called a dgee (gee and jee, I suppose, are also acceptable) a jay."

Comment: Give us some examples.  You're not making a lot of sense.

Comment: Are you sure he wasn't just using the slashes to indicate italics? That's a common way of writing letters-as-letters (e.g., “That's misspelled: there's no _q_ in _finger_”). Personally I'd just write the letter with no special notation or formatting at all (“There's no q in _finger_”), but I think it's mainly a matter of preference. At least I don't recall coming across any style guides offering an opinion on the matter.

Comment: I have updated it, giving examples -- the same thrice.

Comment: You mean  /a/, “b”, (c), or ⟨d⟩, or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Grapheme" might be a useful word in this situation.

I believe the correct way to indicate a single letter (and not the sound it makes) is just as you remember from the international phonetic alphabet: by enclosing it in angle brackets. http://www.languagegeek.com/roman/conventions.html

`Gary accidentally called a <g> a <j>.`

In casual written English, I might personally just go with quotation marks (`called a "g" a "j"`) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you. I was unforsure. I shall remake my keyboard layout to bind the angle brackets at once. I need to add guillemettes, and some other quotation mark styles anyhow.